# Ubuntu server crashes during installation

Tags: ubuntu, boot, system-installation

While installing, the Ubuntu server 22.04, it crashed.
I tried to install it with an usb-stick and uefi.
I attempted to install it around 15 times and the interesting thing is that it did not crash a the same point. Sometimes while selecting the Language, others during the keyboard selection and other while choosing the installation medium.
The Laptop is an Aspire 7 from Acer
With:
Intel 7
Nvidia 960M (I know there might be problems, but Ubuntu server has a terminal installation)
I ran CentOS on it before and remember that there was a problem at booting into it, but I had solved it with renaming the .efi files and disabling secure boot.
Here are the crash logs.\

They are to big so I uploaded them here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d7PGTflD8rRjhDRwhDsqF61D6iZYf6_E/view?usp=sharing